# SOLR searching multiple dynamic field _b boolean fields at the same time

Tags: solr, coldfusion

I am using Coldfusion 2018 cfsearch which uses SOLR.

When I do a search on a dynamic boolean field like so, it works and returns correct results.

```
<CFSEARCH
   name = "GetResults"
   collection = "mycollection" 
   criteria="is_ethics_b:1"
>
```

For the life of me I can't figure how to search other dynamic boolean field at the same time. I tried:

```
is_ethics_b:1 is_visible_b:0
is_ethics_b:1 AND is_visible_b:0
(is_ethics_b:1) (is_visible_b:0)
is_ethics_b:true is_visible_b:false
is_ethics_b:true AND is_visible_b:false
```

I have tried other countless combinations but I can't figure it out. Anyone has suggestions?

UPDATE: It seems like you can only search one boolean _b field at a time? I ended up changing all my boolean _b to integer _i fields. It appears to work for my purpose.

is_ethics_i:1 is_visible_i:0

Comment: `is_ethics_b:1 AND is_visible_b:0` should work fine in regular Solr queries as far as I can tell. Try the query directly to Solr first to see if you get the result you want, then check if there's an issue with how the query is given in cfsearch if the results don't match.

Comment: Did you try `criteria=' ""is_ethics_b:1"" AND ""is_visible_b:0"" '>` ? This is the syntax used [here](https://www.3gpp2.org/cfdocs/htmldocs/Developing/WS82937B1B-240F-4850-B376-5FD9F911E5E5.html) for an OR query.

Comment: When I try criteria=' ""is_ethics_b:1"" AND ""is_visible_b:0"" '> I get the message: 
cannot convert the value "1"" AND ""is_visible_b:0""" to a boolean

Comment: When I try is_ethics_b:1 AND is_visible_b:0, I get the message: cannot convert the value "1 AND is_visible_b:0" to a boolean, I don't know where to test the query directly to Solr on the Coldfusion server. I can't find it anywhere on the CF Admin side.

Comment: I ended up changing all my boolean _b to integer _i fields. It appears to work for my purpose.